# Post Commit SVN hook on MediaTemple (gs) - svn update

Tags: svn, permissions, hook, mediatemple

I have created a SSH/FTP/email user and when I connect to my MTServer using SSH and that user I can't access /home/XXXX/domains/mydomain.com/.

I am using subversion and it's working fine, but I want it to be able to auto update my webpage ( on the MTServer ) everytime I commit.

The post-commit hook works fine, because had tested with
echo "did run" >> error_log;

But svn update is not working.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the group and user settings are properly configured. If SVN has a different user than the one you're logging in with, make sure all files are group-writable, and both accounts belong to the same group.

Comment: How can I know the SVN user ? or user group ?

Comment: `ls -al` will tell you who owns the files and what their permissions are.

Comment: It's the same owner and the same usergroup.

Comment: Got it to work thanks, I had just checked all permissions associated with the files in question.